# Find the data-id in the table to remove and add the class

Tags: jquery

I am working on my jquery code to find the data-id in same row as where I clicked on so I could be able to remove the class and add the new class.

I have a table as follows:

```
<tr class="unread" data-id="235'" data-sort="1556479689">
    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
        <div id="235'" name="mail_checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="mail_checkbox1" name="mail_checkbox1" class="mail-check" unchecked="">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="unread" data-id="234'" data-sort="1556479689">
    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
        <div id="235'" name="mail_checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="mail_checkbox1" name="mail_checkbox1" class="mail-check" unchecked="">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="unread" data-id="233'" data-sort="1556479689">
    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
        <div id="235'" name="mail_checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="mail_checkbox1" name="mail_checkbox1" class="mail-check" unchecked="">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

When I tried this:

```
$(".tbody_maillist").find("tr").each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('unread');
    $(this).addClass('read');
});
```

It wont remove the class `unread` to add the new class called `read` in the same row as where I clicked on the row. For e.g When I click on the row where it have the data-id `235`, then remove the class `unread` and add the new class `read`.

Here is the full code:

```
$(document).on('click','#mail_check', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var email_number = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-id');
    email_number = email_number.replace("'", '');


    $("#mail_checkbox1").each(function() {
        $(".tbody_maillist").find("tr").each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('unread');
        $(this).addClass('read');
    });
});
```

What I am trying to achieve is when I click in a row where it have the data-id `235`, `234`, `233` or whatever it is, then I want to remove the class and add the new class.

Can you please show me an example how I could search for the `data-id` using the variable called `email_number` so I could then remove the class and add the new class?

Thank you.

Comment: *when I click in a row* you mean the row, or the checkbox? Please note that you cannot ever have more than one element with any given `id` value. Also note that checkboxes do not have a `unchecked` attribute, rendering your HTML invalid.

Comment: First of all you cannot have multiple ids with the same name. Each Id should be unique. 
Listen to `$(document).on('click','.mail_check', ...` instead. 
Data can be captured using the data method. `$(el).data('id')`

Comment: @connexo yes I mean when I click on the row not the checkbox.

Comment: `#mail_check` should be `.mail-check` by looking at your html and `mail_checkbox1 ` is an ID and need to be unique

Comment: @Lasithds I do understand that but i want to search for the the data-id after when I click on the row so I want to remove the class and add the new class. How I could do that?

Comment: @RobertJones So when someone clicks the checkbox, the toggling of classes should not happen?

Comment: @Huangism if I change it to `.mail-check`, can I be able to find the `data-id` that I want to remove and add the class?

Comment: @connexo oh right, i understand that so what change i need to make in order to get it working correctly?

Comment: @connexo I have tried `$(".tbody_maillist").find(email_number).removeClass('unread');` but it wont remove the class when I am searching for the email number. Any idea? :(

Comment: You haven't answered my last question.

Comment: @connexo Oh sorry, I didn't realised that. Well no when I click the checkboxes, nothing will happens.

Comment: @RobertJones yea you can find it the same way with closest

Comment: @Huangism How? can you post the answer to show men an example how I could use it with closest to find the data-id using the variable called `email_number` so I could remove and add the class?

Comment: `$("[data-id=" + email_number + "]").removeClass('unread').addClass('read')
    });` your code has lot of errors in the html. You would have to correct the html first. Example here https://jsfiddle.net/wsumvja3/

Comment: I really advise to stop using jQuery, otherwise you will never understand the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your html has some errors, I cleaned it up and this js will work

I had to remove the `'` in your `data-id`, that should be removed when you output the tables.

I removed the Id for each input as they were the same name and Id must be unique.
I updated the name attribute for each input to different names.

These cleanups should of been done when the code is generated

```js
$('.mail-check').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var email_number = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-id');

    $("[data-id=" + email_number + "]").removeClass('unread').addClass('read')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class="unread" data-id="235" data-sort="1556479689">
    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
        <div id="235'" name="mail_checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="" name="mail_checkbox1" class="mail-check" unchecked="">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="unread" data-id="234" data-sort="1556479689">
    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
        <div id="235'" name="mail_checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="" name="mail_checkbox2" class="mail-check" unchecked="">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>


<tr class="unread" data-id="233" data-sort="1556479689">
    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
        <div id="235'" name="mail_checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="" name="mail_checkbox3" class="mail-check" unchecked="">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for this. Here's a plain vanilla JS solution using a delegate listener on the `.tbody_maillist` element that checks what was clicked when the click occurs:

```js
document.querySelector('.tbody_maillist').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === "INPUT") return; // do nothing, the checkbox was clicked
  const tr = event.target.matches('tr') ? event.target : event.target.closest('tr');
  tr.classList.toggle('unread');
  tr.classList.toggle('read');
})
```

```css
.unread { background-color: #f8f8f8 }
.read { background-color: green }
```

```html
<table id="foo" width="100%">
  <tbody class="tbody_maillist">
  <tr class="unread" data-id="235'" data-sort="1556479689">
    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
      <div id="235'" name="mail_checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="mail_checkbox1" name="mail_checkbox1" class="mail-check">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="unread" data-id="234'" data-sort="1556479689">
    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
      <div id="235'" name="mail_checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="mail_checkbox2" name="mail_checkbox1" class="mail-check">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="unread" data-id="233'" data-sort="1556479689">
    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
      <div id="235'" name="mail_checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="mail_checkbox3" name="mail_checkbox1" class="mail-check">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```